# Is it possible to render to multiple devices / monitors in XNA?

Tags: xna, multiple-graphics-devices

As the title.

If so, how?

As well as wiring it up correctly, how should I manage syncing GPU resources and update/draw steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at this article:

http://glassarrow.blogspot.com/2009/02/xna-c-how-to-create-full-screen.html

And to these discussion :

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/10227/53871.aspx

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/568847-fullscreen-over-multiple-monitors-in-xna/